# Subclass constructor

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

I created a superclass (Person) & a subclass (Student)

```
public class Person{
private String name;
private Date birthdate;
//0-arg constructor
public Person() {
    birthdate = new Date("January", 1, 1000);
    name = "unknown name";
}
//2-arg constructor
public Person(String newName, Date newBirthdate){
    this.name = newName;
    this.birthdate = newBirthdate;
}

//Subclass
public class Student extends Person{

    public Student(){
        super(name, birthdate)
}
```

I get the error: cannor reference name & birthdate before supertype cosntructor has been called.
I tried:

```
public Student(){
    super()
}
```

but my course tester says I should use `super(name, birthdate);`

Answer (score 4):

If your default constructor for `Student` needs to use the two-argument constructor of `Person`, you'll have to define your subclass like this:

```
public class Student extends Person{

    public Student() {
        super("unknown name", "new Date("January", 1, 1000));
    }

    public Student(String name, Date birthdate) {
        super(name, birthdate);
    }
}
```

Note also that `Person.name` and `Person.birthdate` are not visible in subclasses because they are declared `private`.

Comment: I already have the 2 parameter constructor.
The thing is i have to use super(name, birthdate) in the 0-param constructor

Comment: @user1200325 - I revised my answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a Student constructor that takes the name and birthday as parameters.

The example you've provided won't work unless the Student is already instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are a few misconceptions here:

When you create `Student`, there isn't a separate `Person` object--there's just a `Student` which has all the properties of a `Person`.

The constructor is what *builds* the Student, so inside the constructor there is no other Student/Person whose fields you could reference. Once you call `super` you've initialized the `Person` portion of the object, and the fields from the `Person` are accessible, but since it's a new object they can't have been set to anything unless you do it in the constructor.

Your options are either to :

1) use the defaults as set up in `Person`:

```
public Student() {
   super(); // this line can be omitted as it's done by default
}
```

2) Take values as parameters and pass them to the `Person` constructor:

```
public Student(String newName, Date newBirthdate) {
    super(newName, newBirthdate);
}
```

3) Provide new defaults:

```
public Student() {
    super("Bob", new Date("January", 1, 1990));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the name and birthdate parameters  for student somehow. How about:

```
public Student(String name, Date birthdate){
    super(name, birthdate)
}
```

you can also do:

```
public Student(){
    super("unknown name", new Date("January", 1, 1000));
}
```

Comment: @Jochen - copy-paste - the root of all evil :)

Comment: I already have the 2 parameter constructor.
The thing is i have to use super(name, birthdate) in the 0-param constructor